# React - Close all other dropdowns when another is open

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm struggling to understand how to change the state of my components so that all the other dropdown menus close when another one is clicked. Something that was fairly simple in Javascript.

```
// Nav Items
showMenuHandler(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  this.setState({ showMenu: !this.state.showMenu });
}

<Item>
  <Link onClick={this.showMenuHandler}>{this.props.children}</Link>
    {
      this.state.showMenu
          ? (
            <Dropdown>
              {this.props.children}
            </Dropdown>
      ) : null
    }
  </Item>
```

Simple condition that switches the state so that the dropDown component opens and close on click. However lets say I have the Item component in multiple places and want to close all of the other Dropdowns before another one opens. What is the best way of doing that?

I had a thought of passing the state from the List component as shown below:

```
<List>
  {NavTitles.map(Title => (
    <NavItem key={Title} open={this.state.showMenu}>{Title}</NavItem>
  ))}
</List>
```

Then I could add a click event to the List component and change the state?

Would this be the best way of solving the issue?

Comment: You would need to have multiple states, one for each item component.

Comment: Add  `<Dropdown onBlur = {() => this.setState({showMenu : !this.state.showMenu})}>`

Comment: Multiple states feels like it is over the top? Is there really not another way to do it? Thanks Naveen but having a blur on the dropdown doesn't fix my issue I'm afraid.